# Before hook on all magento frontend controller-actions [Magento]

Tags: php, magento

I would like to perform a particular operation

- Make an outside API update OR
- Redirect to a different path , etc

when any frontend url is requested with a particular get parameter.

```
e.g domain.com/checkout/cart?process=true
```

Is there anyway a module of mine can detect when a request is made with a particular parameter ?

Comment: you can look into event and observers

Answer (score 4):

You can use the event `controller_action_predispatch`. This is called in the `preDispatch` method of each controller.
Inside your observer you can get any parameter from `$_GET` like this:

```
$param = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('param_name_here');
```

And you can do a redirect like this:

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()
    ->getResponse()
    ->setRedirect('URL GOES HERE')
    ->sendResponse();
exit; //it seams that this exit is important.
```

Comment: Ah, great. Just what I looking for. ! Thanks, shall give it a go.

Comment: @Marius I have used the event controller_action_predispatch and in my observer I am redirecting to home page again if user is not logged in using above code. But still it goes into redirect loop.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write an observer method and call it on "controller_action_layout_load_before" event to get parameters.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks. Can I perform "redirects" from inside the event handler ?